# Dump File MySQL 5.6.10

Tags: mysql, dump

I was trying to create a dump file from my MySQL database, but when I try it always gives me this error

> Operation failed with exitcode 2

```
16:06:07 Dumping proactivetraindb (userstate)

Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-extra-file="h:\docume~1\anarita\locals~1\temp\tmpde5rwy.cnf"  --user=root --max_allowed_packet=1G --host=localhost --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 "proactivetraindb" "userstate"

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)
```

The version of MySQl is 5.6.10  but the version of MySQLDump is 5.5.16

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: Give us the content of tmpde5rwy.cnf, or give us death!!

Comment: waht is tmpde5rwy.cnf?

Comment: Its your options file, for global option for the mysql dump command....the problem may be is in that file "--defaults-extra-file="h:\docume~1\anarita\locals~1\temp\tmpde5rwy.cnf" --"....saludos ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As outlined by a previous answer, but just to clarify further: This is for MySQL in Windows.

I was having the exact same issue while trying to dump data out of a table on a local test server, and based on the previous answer, this is how I did it.

1. Find your mysql original download folder, and look in the `/bin` folder, there should be a `mysqldump.exe`.
2. Go into Workbench Preferences: `Edit -> Preferences -> Administrator -> Path` to mysqldump Tool, and enter in the path to the mysqldump.exe that you found.
3. Save by pressing "OK" and restarting Workbench.
4. Open up terminal, but typing in `cmd` in the Search area of the start menu (Windows 7), and find the sql folder you found in step 1, and cd into bin. It should look like `C:\...\bin>`. Here, type in `mysqldump -t -u [username] -p [database name] [tablename]`. This should dump the data from the `[tablename]` table into the dump folder as designated in Workbench.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This also works by using the workbench export tool...very nifty!! Thanks Maelstrom!

Comment: I'm getting this error without Workbench involved at all. Just `mysqldump -u root [database name] > dump.sql` gives me this error.

Comment: I had two versions of my sql server on my device. I tried the full path to the 4.1 mysqldump version which failed. Then I tried the full path the 5.6 mysqldump version which worked.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same error in MySQL Workbench.

1. Find out where is the mysqldump tools provided by your install of MySQL 5.6. On my mac it was at "usr/local/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin/mysqldump".
2. Then I set up this path in MySQL Workbench/Preferences/Administrator/Path to mysqldump Tool
3. Give MySQL Workbench a restart.

It should work.

Comment: Mine was in this location in Finder: `Mac HD: /Shared Items/Public/mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86_64/bin`
Thanks for the post Vespucci75fr

Comment: For Windows : %programfiles%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

Answer (score 20):

The reason for this is that MySQL 5.6 has removed support for "SET OPTION" and your mysql client tools are probably on older version. Most likely 5.5 or 5.1. There is more info about this issue on MySQL bugs website.

The quickest solution is to update your mysql client tools to 5.6 and your problem will be solved. If you are on Linux platform, here is a solution that worked great for me:
http://www.markomedia.com.au/mysqldump-mysql-5-6-problem-solved/

Answer (score 6):

You must use mysqldump 5.6.x to be able to dump mysql 5.6 database, because MySQL 5.6 discontinued and removed support for SET OPTION syntax.
Under 32/64bit Windows you must do:
1.1. (32bit win) Download Windows (x86, 32-bit), ZIP Archive  5.6.19 212.3M http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (direct link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=452188) 
1.2. (64bit win)  Download Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive  5.6.19 217.2M http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ (direct link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=452189) 
2. Extract mysqldump.exe from just downloaded file mysql-5.6.19-win32(64).zip (from /mysql-5.6.19-win32(64)/bin/mysqldump.exe) 
3. Replace this just extracted file with your already installed mysqldump.exe file (instalation dir/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe)

Answer (score 4):

Using Windows 7, a far easier solution for me was to find mysqldump.exe from; ***C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe***

copy it and then replace the MySQL workbench mysqldump.exe which is located in the root of workbench ***C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\mysqldump.exe***

Restart MySQL workbench and all should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Amazon RDS, right?
You can just get the newer version of mysqldump, v5.6 and use it instead.

Download the portable zip here and extract just the mysql\mysqldump.exe there.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/

I tried it just now and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Window 10`. Your `Mysql server` would have been installed in `C:\Program Files\MySQL` directory and rest all components are installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL`.
Go to `MySql Workbench`>`Edit`>`Preferences`. A window will open, click the Administrator tab and mention the path of your `mysqldump.exe` (which is present in `C:\Program Files\MySQL`). Restart your workbench.

Thanks, Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

In Workbench look for Preferences: Edit -> Preferences -> Administrator -> Path to the mysqldump Tool. Browse your MySQL folder inside the bin folder and look for mysqldump.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on the Amazon EC2 acessing a RDS Mysql 5.6 database. I just ran

sudo apt-get upgrade

It didn't update mysql client to 5.6, but mysqldump now is working fine.

Comment: it didn't work for me and I wish I had that time back :(

Answer (score 0):

For Mac it depends on your installation.
If you used a dmg file to install it, you need to find the bin directory.
mine was under `/usr/local/mysql/bin`
You will find mysqldump file under this folder.
Now provide this location in your 
Preferences -> Administrator -> Path to mysqldump Tool as `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump`
You should be good to export now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, update mysql-client to latest version. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-client
```

did the job for me.

```
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
```

Mine got updated to 5.5 and mysqldump now works for me. This is on Amazon RDS with MySQL 5.6.x

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a linux machine, this is provided by the `mysql-client` package. Installing that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility, I needed `MySQL 5.6.41` on my Windows 10 machine, so I used the `5.6.41 MySQL installer` to install "All" (My Workbench, MySQL, connectors, etc).

Even though I used the installer for version 5.6.41, it installed `Workbench 8.0`, as well as version 8.0 of the various connectors, etc.
So of course, I got a similar error.

There seems to be no easy way to force lower version of MySQL Workbench to be installed instead (On my previous machine, before workbench 8.0, did NOT have this conflict when installed).

**Solution that worked for me:**

1. Find the version of `mysqldump.exe` that matches the version of MySQL you're using:

   - From Windows Explorer, I searched my machine for all versions of `mysqldump.exe`
   - Right-clicked each `mysqldump.exe` it found -> `Properties` -> `Details` tab.
   - Found the version `5.6.41` (matching the MySQL version I'm running)
   - Clicked back to the `General` tab, to see the folder path that that version of mysqldump.exe was installed in
   - `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin`, in my case
     (version 8.0 was installed in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE`)
2. Now open MySQL Workbench..

   - Edit -> Preferences -> Administration -> Path to mysqldump Tool
   - Paste in the file path for the appropriate version of `mysqldump.exe` (including the file name!)
   - Click `OK`
   - Restart MySQL Workbench

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This worked for me.  However, I have no idea how to make this work if you have two versions of MySQL on your machine, say MySQL 5.6 and 5.7, or 8.0.
So when I upgrade (any/some/all of) my cloud servers to version 5.7, this looks to be another challenge to overcome. Since Workbench only allows a single `mysqldump.exe` file, to be used no matter which version of my local MySQL server is running...  Or perhaps manually change the path location, each time open a connection that uses the Port to the *other* MySQL version (and remember to change it back after?).

*For this reason, I `Removed` MySQL 5.7 completely*, and will hence keep all cloud (and my local) servers at 5.6 for the time being - a Project for another day.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users to save your time, mysqldump is in "mysql-community-client_5.7.26-1ubuntu16.04_i386.deb " package

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I put a couple of different answers together.

The pro for me was, that I could switch easily between 5.6, 8, ... without having to up/downgrade ubuntu dependencies each time.

The easiest way for me on Ubuntu was to just download the 5.6 (or 5.7, whatever you want) mysqldump binary and change that in workbench.
Everything went well after that:

1. go to https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/ and download the correct version you want (for me: 5.6.47 for 64x)
2. Unpack the archive somewhere, you can find later
3. Change the mysqldump binary in mysql workbench: Edit -> Preferences -> Administrator -> "Path to mysqldump Tool" to `{{YOUR_UNPACKED_FOLDER}}/bin/mysqldump`
4. Save it with `Ok`

Now you should be able to just export and it will use mysqldump 5.x.

Answer (score -1):

I have **Mysql 5.6.12** version. `SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1` is working fine in my machine.
now i am able to take a dump of sql.

> mysql> SET SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00
>   sec)

worked for me.

Comment: The unfortunate mysqldump versions try to execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' , notice the extra 'OPTION' word.