# MySQL 5.6 / Data export doesn't work (dumping data)

Tags: mysql

What I've been trying to do is to send some data from MySQL to other computers.

I searched the internet for a solution and the best way is probably to put the data into a file, by using the export function.

Soon I encountered an error. Here is part of the log.

```
Running: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" 
--defaults-file="c:\users\takaha\appdata\local\temp\tmpx2hr0e.cnf"  
--enable-cleartext-plugin --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp 
--port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --events --skip-triggers "db_student_comments"
mysqldump: unknown option '--enable-cleartext-plugin'

Operation failed with exitcode 2
14:44:03 Export of C:\Users\takaha\Documents\dumps\Dump20150212.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

Apparently, this error is similar to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227171/dump-file-mysql-5-6-10), but trying the first and second advice on this page didn't solve it, and I've spent more than two days in this problem so far.

I'll put a image of my cmd, since using cmd was recommended at other Stackoverflow pages. This image shows the dumping seems to have successfully been done, but I don't know where the file is. (The "dump" folder was automatically created in C:\Users\username\Documents, but this folder is empty.)[image]

I'd appreciate any advice.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Danyal, this was solved.
All I had to do was to exactly indicate the directory to create the file after ">".

Comment: you can simply use
 mysqldump -u'username' -p'password' database_name > back_up.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use this command?

```
 mysqldump -u'username' -p'password' database_name > back_up.sql
```

You need to have mysql in the environment variable. If it isn't there, you can go to mysql's bin directory and can execute this command.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But after this command is executed, it says that the access was denied.

Comment: what username are you using? use root and password of root..probably the user you are using doesn't have the permissions

Comment: The access issue was solved, but now cmd says that 'Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure'.

Comment: By the way, `back_up.sql` on you answer is a file name, which I can determine, is it correct?

Comment: YES... do it like mysqldump -uroot -p databasename > file.sql . ..it will then ask you to enter the password...entering the password is insecure history of commands can be seen which can reveal the password to others.

Comment: you can save it in any directory the path can be d:/folder/file.sql ...you can create a test database and load back the file to verify it by command mysql -uroot -p database < file.sql     ( sign  < is used to load back).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70831/discussion-between-ymd-and-danyal-sandeelo).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html):

> The `mysql`, `mysqladmin`, and `mysqlslap` client programs support an `--enable-cleartext-plugin` option that enables the plugin on a per-invocation basis.

It does not appear to be a valid option for `mysqldump`. You shouldn't need it at all unless you're using non-standard MySQL authentication.